# Using Activity ktx with viewmodel and java

Tags: java, kotlin, viewmodel

I have a piece of code where i need to instantiate my viewmodel using the activity library , i tried to do so in java but nothing seems to be working for me

- This is the code in kotlin and i want to convert it to java

```
   mainViewModel : MainViewModel by ViewModels()
```

Comment: If you want to use delegation in Java similarly to what kotlin documentation suggest I guess you can use:

 private val viewModel by viewModelProvider { 
            (applicationContext as YourApp).component.MainViewModel() 
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, use `ViewModelProvider` in `onCreate` method:

```
private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainViewModel  = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
}
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement

Comment: thank you for the answer  , i know it this way but since in activity library documentation , they provide activity ktx which is for kotlin and also activity ( without ktx ) for java , what is the job of the latter ?

Comment: @takieddine https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

Comment: this is what i'm talking about https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity , as you can see to init viewmodel in kotlin , we use activity ktx , but for java they provide the normal one

Comment: @takieddine usually ktx libraries depends on Java libraries and provide extension functions for Kotlin, for example `androidx.activity:activity-ktx` depends on `androidx.activity:activity` and provides Kotlin extensions such as `viewModels`